# List comprehension returning two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to do a list comprehension on two lists returning 2 variables in result.

Using for loop:

```
foo = [1,2,3]
bar = [4,5,6]

for f, b in zip(foo, bar):
    print(f, b)
```

However, when I try to use list comprehension to do the same execution, it throws a SyntaxError

```
print(f,b) for f, b in zip(foo, bar)
```

Comment: List comprehensions are for building lists. You're not trying to build a list.

Comment: You shouldn't use list comprehensions for side effects, stick to the first loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the whole thing in square brackets. Like this:

```py
[print(f, b) for f, b in zip(foo, bar)]
```

That's because you are doing the action in the first bit `print(f, b)` for every elements (f, b) in the tuple you get from the zip function.